# Read user's properties back from program-y's convo file

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot

I am trying to save and read the user's properties from file.
Currently, I can save his properties to the plain text file.
I had tried read the [official document](https://github.com/keiffster/program-y/wiki/AIML-Cookbook), but I couldn't find the answer since it is being developed

`config.yml`

```
brain:

    # Overrides
    overrides:
      allow_system_aiml: true
      allow_learn_aiml: true
      allow_learnf_aiml: true

    # Defaults
    defaults:
      default-get: unknown
      default-property: unknown
      default-map: unknown
      learnf-path: $BOT_ROOT/aimlf

    # Nodes
    nodes:
      pattern_nodes: $BOT_ROOT/config/pattern_nodes.conf
      template_nodes: $BOT_ROOT/config/template_nodes.conf

    # Binary
    binaries:
      save_binary: false
      load_binary: false
      binary_filename: /tmp/y-bot.brain
      load_aiml_on_binary_fail: false

    # Braintree
    braintree:
      file: /tmp/braintree.xml
      content: xml

    files:
        aiml:
            files: $BOT_ROOT/aiml
            extension: .aiml
            directories: true
            errors:
              file: /tmp/y-bot_errors.csv
              format: csv
              encoding: utf-8
              delete_on_start: false
            duplicates:
              file: /tmp/y-bot_duplicates.csv
              format: csv
              encoding: utf-8
              delete_on_start: false
            conversations:

              # User's properties
              type: file
              config_name: file_storage
              empty_on_start: false
              file_storage:
                dir: $BOT_ROOT/conversations
            # Bot's properties
            properties: $BOT_ROOT/config/properties.txt
```

`Console.convo`

```
topic:*
gender:MALE
name:john
lastname:conor
gendername:I like to stay informed.
firstname:friend
```

**Question:**
How do I load user's properties back to bot?

Answer (score 0):

My full `config.yaml` file has upper nested section. It is a clone of `y-bot`. But now it is gone already from the repository.

```
conversations:
  type: file
  config_name: file_storage
  empty_on_start: true
```

Just change `true` to `false`. That's all!